# Filter dates in a table based on the current date

Tags: excel, vba, filter

I want to dynamically filter dates in a table based on the current date.

I get error 438 with the below code (and variations).

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects.ListColumns(5).Range.AutoFilter Field:=5,Criteria1:=">=" & Date
```

Comment: `.ListObjects` ... you need to refer to a specific one, either by index: `.ListObjects(1)` or by name `.ListObjects("Table1")`.

Comment: Perhaps a tip: work with variables: `Dim tbl As ListObject`, `Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("YourTableName")`. Then work with `tbl` when referring to `.ListColumns(5)` and filtering. Breaking the monster line into smaller, shorter lines should help debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### AutFilter Date Column

- The criteria needs to be a string:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub FilterByToday()
    Dim Crit1 As String: Crit1 = ">=" & Format(Date, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter 5, Crit1
End Sub
```

- This doesn't work for me, possibly because my date separator is a dot unless I change `Crit1` to:

  ```
  Crit1 = ">=" & Format(Date, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") ' note the backslashes
  ```

Comment: This has worked perfectly, thank you so much for your help!